# How can I capture tethered traffic and save it as a pcap file?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, networking, tethering

I use my Android device with 3G as a hotspot for my laptop. I also occasionally connect other Internet devices to the network, and would like to look at the traffic.

I need a way to log the traffic on my Android device, and a way to save it as a pcap file so I can use it for Wireshark on my laptop.

What's the best way of doing this? Using Android 2.3.7.

Comment: This feature needs a rooted device. If you have CyanogenMod 7.2, it haa root and tcpdump already included.

Answer (score -1):

You need this soft which capture packet on android

http://lost-and-found-narihiro.blogspot.ru/2012/11/packet-capture-on-android-tpacket.html